# How to unit test global validation?

Tags: unit-tests

Let's say my program takes two **required** arguments: `--opt-a` and `--opt-b`. I want to test every single validation: two test cases here, one if `--opt-a` is missing, and another one when `--opt-b` is missing.

I am using [Apache Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) to parse the arguments passed to my program. The [`CommandLineParser.parse()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/cli/CommandLineParser.html#parse-org.apache.commons.cli.Options-java.lang.String:A-) method throws a ParseException if one required option is missing or has a wrong format. Note that I chose Commons CLI for the sake of simplicity, but the problem would remain the same if I wrote the validation code by myself.

The tests would look like this:

1. Let's test when option A is missing:

   ```java
   @Test
   void givenRequiredOptionAIsMissing_shouldThrowException {
     String[] args = new String[] {
       "--opt-b", "foo"
     };

     ParseException exc = assertThrows(ParseException.class, () -> MyProgram.run(args));
     assertEquals("`--opt-a` is required", exc.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   Fine, the test passes. But I needed to add `--opt-b` to make it pass. Anyway.
2. Now let's test when option B is missing:

   ```java
   @Test
   void givenRequiredOptionBIsMissing_shouldThrowException {
     String[] args = new String[] {
       "--opt-a", "bar"
     };

     ParseException exc = assertThrows(ParseException.class, () -> MyProgram.run(args));
     assertEquals("`--opt-b` is required", exc.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   It also passes. But I have the symmetric problem: I needed to add `--opt-a` to make it pass.

But I'm not very happy with these tests because:

1. I need to add the other argument that has nothing to do with the current test;
2. if I add another required option, all my tests break.

It is not the first time I stumble upon this kind of input **global validation** testing problem, not necessarily using a tool such as Common CLI.

How to make my test isolated from one to another?

Comment: >I want to test every single validation. What about other possible scenarios e.g - no arguments specified, two arguments specified (one correct argument, one invalid argument), two arguments specified (both invalid), more than two arguments specified?

Comment: @Prome Well, I didn't want my question to be too verbose. In fact, I already have a test that covers an empty `String[] args`. But the problems I mentioned appeared really soon, even before testing the other special cases you are talking about.